# JQuery Fancybox not loading

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have the following simple code to display an image in a fancybox when "Open Window" is clicked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Add fancyBox -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {    
           $("a#fancybox").fancybox();
       });      
    </script>
</head>
<body>
   <a id="fancybox" class="fancybox" href="welcome.png">open window</a>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I click the link, the image displays but not in a fancybox. IE's debugger gives the following error:

`SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'fancybox'`

Why is that error happening? How can I get the fancybox to work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

in the documentations they are using it with id tag and not class :: 
html :

```
 <a id="single_image" href="image_big.jpg"><img src="image_small.jpg" alt=""/></a>
```

js :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* This is basic - uses default settings */

    $("a#single_image").fancybox();
// do stuff 
}
```

but try to specify that you are using links in the selector, try : $("a.fancybox")

documentation & examples :: http://fancybox.net/howto

Comment: Thanks. I changed it to use id instead of class (and edited the question), but it still doesn't display in a fancybox and IE is still throwing that error. I looked at the documentation and my code looks the same as their samples. Any idea why it doesn't work??

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you need to fix your `<head>` tag. Try adding an opening `<head>` tag to avoid script loading issues

Comment: Thanks. I added the missing <head> tag, but no change.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no errors in your JavaScript or HTML, it's likely that the issue is in your included scripts. Make sure that your path to the fancybox script and stylesheet are correct. 
Good Luck!